# Bash script if - else contitions

Tags: debian, shell-script, password

I would like to do create a bash script that downloads a specific installer from the internet, installs it, create a desktop file that launches it, make it auto start, then remove the installer, but there are a few things I would like the script to check. These things are:

- the existence of the installer (if not existing, then download it, else set it executable)
- the existence of a previous installation (if exists, then set it's uninstaller executable, run it and remove everything it left behind, else go to next step)
- the state of the gksu package via apt list | grep gksu (if it's installed, then go to next step, else install it) and
- the output of gksu example.run (if there's a "GNOME_SUDO_PASS" line, then repeat gksu example.run, else go to next step)

Comment: Please read [this](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask), then edit your question.

Answer (score 1):

> Condition: installer - ls . | grep example.runchmod +x pelda.run else
>   wget download/link/of/example.run

As I understand the above, it translates to:

```
if [ -f example.run ]
then
    chmod +x pelda.run
else
    wget download/link/of/example.run
fi
```

`[ -f example.run ]` is an example of using the `test` command.  If a file named `example.run` exists, then the test command set a return code of 0 (meaning true).  If it doesn't, it sets a return code of 1 (meaning false).

> Condition: gksu - apt list --installed | grep gksu, if !exists, then
>   sudo apt install gksu else gksu pelda.run

As I interpret the above, it translates to:

```
if apt list --installed | grep gksu
then
    gksu pelda.run
else
    sudo apt install gksu
fi
```

Here, we are using the fact that `grep` sets a return code depending on whether it finds a match or not.  `apt list --installed` returns a list of installed packages.  If its output anywhere contains the string `gksu`, then `grep` sets a return code of 0 (meaning true) and the `then` clause is executed.  If it doesn't, the `else` clause is executed.

Comment: Sorry if was not clear enough.
"if [ -f example.run ]" was what i tried first. But it will download the file even if it's existing, but yes that's what i would like to do. You misunderstood the gksu condition.  What i would like to fid out with it is that the gksu package is installed or not on the computer. If installed, go to the next step, if not, then install it.

Comment: (1) _""if [ -f example.run ]" was what i tried first. But it will download the file even if it's existing"_  No, it won't.  If the `example.run` exists in the _current_ directory, then the script will run `chmod +x pelda.run`.   (2) I have updated the gksu example as per your info.

Comment: @WeylynSavan Very good.

Comment: Now the gksu part:
apt list --installed | grep "gksu/" > tmp
while read gksu
do
if [ "[installed]" ]
then
  gksu example.run
else
  sudo apt install gksu
fi
done < tmp
At this point the content of tmp is:
gksu/unknown,now 2.0.2-60 amd64 [installed]
But it won't install gksu if it's not installed (tried in vm without gksu installed).

Comment: That code is very different.  Among other possible issues, this part won't work as you would like it to: `... if [ "[installed]" ] then ...`